# Capistrano suddenly stops using public key

Tags: ssh, vps, capistrano, keychain

I'm trying [Capistrano](http://capify.org) to deploy to a VPS where I have public key access to my user *foo*. For deployment, I created another user *deploy*, set up my key into it's `authorized_keys`, configured capistrano to use this user and did a **succesful** `cap deploy:setup`. From then on, I couldn't log passwordless into *deploy@vps* anymore, with or without capistrano. My key works because ssh'ing into *foo@vps* works as always. I'm a little lost here..

I'm using keychain 2.7.1 for key management, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be Yet Another Permission Problem™.

```
Jan 01 17:47:20 [sshd] Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/deploy
```

It had `720`... changed it to `700` and it worked. I still don't know how it
got changed (`adduser` created it with `700`) but I suspect that capistrano did
that somehow. So I'll accept the answer that explains that :)